# Abort when key is pressed

Tags: infinite-loop

Is it possible to abort a while loop when a key is pressed?

Lets say I have this code

t=0;
While[t<10!,Print[t];t++]

Is there a way to stop this loop when I press space?
Is there a command like "keypressed"?

Comment: There's `Alt+.`, but take a look at CellEventActions and friends if you want.

Comment: that will do I guess. thanks Kuba

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EventHandler.html) might do what you want.  I'll adapt your example a little to make it more practical.  I'll also use a mouse click instead of a key press for this first example as the key press is only active while the output is "focused" and it is hard to select the output long enough to do that.

```
DynamicModule[{stop = False},
  EventHandler[
    Dynamic[t],
    {"MouseClicked" :> (stop = True)}
  ] // Print;
  t = 0; While[t < 11! && ! stop, t++]
];
```

This gives you a running computation that stops when the [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) output is clicked.

If a key press rather than a mouse click is vital then it seems you will need a static area in the output so that focus is easy to maintain.  Here is an example of that using the key <kbd>x</kbd> to terminate the computation.

```
DynamicModule[{stop = False},
  EventHandler[
    Row[{"(inactive area) ", Dynamic[t]}],
    {{"KeyDown", "x"} :> (stop = True)}
  ] // Print;
  t = 0; While[t < 11! && ! stop, t++]
];
```

Click inside "inactive area" to move the cursor to that location, then press x to terminate.

Comment: thanks for making these examples. I read about Mouseover and keydown in the documentation while I was searching for a solution.Isn't it a bit strange that there is not a built in like Keypressed to do this thing?I think other simple languages have this feature